# Checkio. Посчитать количество определенных слов в строке

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, текст

есть ф-ия

```
def count_words(text, words)
```

есть тест

```
count_words("How aresjfhdskfhskd you?", {"how", "are", "you", "hello"}) == 3
```

---

```
def count_words(text, words):
r = 0
for w in words:
    if w in text:
        r+=1
return r
```

Результат получается равный 2, что не верно.

---

Решение:

```
def count_words(text, words):
r = 0
for w in words:
    if w.lower() in text.lower():
        r+=1
return r
```

Comment: не помещайте решение (ответ) в ваш вопрос -- опубликуйте свой ответ, если необходимо -- [это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неверно, потому что "***H***ow" и "***h***ow" - лишь одинаковые слова по смыслу, но разные по написанию, соответственно, эти строки не равны друг другу. Поэтому интерпретатор считает, что `w in text` это `False`, и инкрементирования переменной `r` не происходит (она не увеличивается на `1`).

P.S. Вы можете использовать встроенные функции `.lower()` или `.upper()`, чтобы регистр обрабатываемых вами строк был единым.

Comment: Действительно это так. Спасибо!

Comment: @Spherastree: для сравнения строк без учёта регистра, можно использовать `.casefold()` метод (`.lower()`, `.upper()` недостаточны в общем случае для произвольного Юникод-текста).

Answer (score 2):

В коде две проблемы:

1. уже упомянутая проблема с регистром, которую можно исправить, используя [`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold)
2. `w in text` ищет подстроки, а не слова. Следует разбить текст на слова (зависит от задачи, что является словом, например: «любая группа символов, несодержащая пробелы» или «любая группа символов, принадлежащих `\w` классу (Unicode word characters)».

Чтобы подсчитать сколько из заданных (уникальных) слов присутствует в заданном тексте (используя сравнение без учёта регистра):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

def count_words(text, words):
    text_words = set(re.findall(r'\w+', text.casefold()))
    return sum(w in text_words for w in set(map(str.casefold, words)))

print(count_words("How aresjfhdskfhskd you?", {"how", "are", "you", "hello"}))
# -> 2
```

Результат `2`, а не `3` потому что `'aresjfhdskfhskd' != 'are'`.

Если хочется считать именно подстроки, вместо отдельных слов:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def count_substr(text, substrs):
    text = text.casefold()
    return sum(s in text for s in set(map(str.casefold, substrs)))

print(count_substr("How aresjfhdskfhskd you?", {"how", "are", "you", "hello"}))
# -> 3
```

[`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) используется, чтобы не считать повторяющиеся строки несколько раз.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = "How aresjfhdskfhskd you?".lower().split()
print({b: l.count(b.lower()) for b in ("hoW", "are", "you", "hello")})

{'are': 0, 'hoW': 1, 'you': 0, 'hello': 0}
```

Comment: 1- следует `.casefold()` вместо `.lower()` для Unicode текста использовать 2- `'you'` не найдено (потому что знак вопроса в тексте после `you` идёт . Разбиение текста на слова по пробелам недостаточно в данном случае. [Можно regex попробовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557374/23044) 3- повторяющиеся слова несколько раз считаются -- не ясно желательно ли это (условие в вопросе можно по разному интерпретировать).